# What are the consequences of a ${\bf O}$(m) algorithm for SAT

Tags: np-hardness, p-vs-np, ds.algorithms, phase-transition

We are given a Boolean formula $F$ in conjunctive normal form with $n$ variables and $m$ clauses and we would like to know if there exists at least one assignment to the $n$ variables that makes $F$ evaluate to True. As we all know this is the famous NP-Complete SAT problem. I would like to know the consequences of being able to solve this problem in time ${\bf O}$($m$). Would this contradict the Phase transition phenomenon that has been shown to exists for the SAT problem? Thank You

PS:If you do not allow repetition of variables in a clause nor repetition of clauses in a formula then you can have up to 3$^{n}$-1 unique clauses.

Comment: This is a polynomial-time algorithm, and would imply that P = NP.

Comment: @George number of clauses $m$ could be exponential in terms of number of variables $n$.

Comment: @user13970: (1) An algorithm is said to take polynomial time if it runs in time polynomial in its input length. For example, an O(m) algorithm for SAT would be linear in its input length. (2) Phase transitions in SAT are generally about satisfiability thresholds (i.e. the clause density at which 50% of randomly generated formulas are satisfiable) rather than hardness thresholds, although the notions are related. The satisfiability threshold is not dependent on the efficiency of SAT algorithms, so I'm not sure what would be contradicted.

Comment: @Huck Bennett I think you are mistaken here because when we talk about the input length of SAT we are talking about number of variables $n$, not number of clauses $m$. $m$ could be exponential in terms of  $n$.

Comment: @user13970: No. The input length means the *total* length of the input. This notion does not change from problem to problem, so there is nothing special "when we talk about the input length of SAT".

Comment: @HuckBennett I am still having hard time understanding this. The best algorithm for 3-SAT runs in time ${\bf O}$($1.32^n$) but this algorithm might run in time greater than that depending on the number of clauses because we can have up to $3^n-1$ many clauses.

Comment: In computational complexity the focus is usually on worst-case analysis.  This means that of interest are sparse instances of SAT (where $m = O(n^k)$ for some constant $k$), precisely because in the general case SAT instances can have $m = \Omega(2^n)$.  Such dense instances are not that interesting from a computational complexity point of view, since (as you state) they can be solved in linear time.

Comment: @AndrásSalamon What I am asking is the possibility of a SAT solver that runs in time proportional to number of clauses. Then that algorithm would run in polynomial time when $m = {\bf O}$($n^k$) for some constant $k$ but not when the number of clauses is exponential in terms of $n$.

Comment: The unsatisfiability threshold for $k$-SAT is also a quite small constant, so instances with $m \ge c_k n$ will be unsatisfiable with high probability.  This means that an algorithm for dense SAT instances really just has to say "no" to be correct most of the time (assuming the input instances are uniformly distributed).  But this does show that dense instances are "uninteresting" in some sense.

Comment: Perhaps I am not clear.  We already have an $O(m)$ algorithm for SAT, if the instances are dense.  The interesting case is when the instances are sparse; then your question simply reduces to "what are the consequences for a linear time SAT algorithm", and you should read Russell Impagliazzo's multiple worlds paper.

Comment: @user13970: A 3SAT instance cannot have more than $8 n^3$ different clauses (assuming all clauses have exactly three literals; more generally it will be $O(n^3)$).

Comment: Welcome to cstheory, a Q&A site for *research-level* questions in *theoretical computer science* (TCS). Your question does not appear to be a research-level question in TCS. Please see the [FAQ] for more information on what is meant by this. Your question might be suitable for [cs.se] which has a broader scope.

Comment: @AndrásSalamon I was able to grasp it now. Then how interesting is it if we have an algorithm that is guaranteed to run in ${\bf O}(m * k)$, where $m$ is the number of clauses and $k$ is the total number of unsatisfying-assignments the given CNF formula has and tell us YES or NO.